# How can I get middleware context from response?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, middleware

I writing error message details and some spesific areas via middleware like this, 
when exists an exception inside of contoller.

await context.Response.WriteAsync(errorDetails.ToString());

Then , I'm trying to get this errordetails from response in TypeScripte' side. When I controlled response which retrun form MVC , I'm not finding the error detail in response object. But I see the error details in Application tab and network tab in Chrome Browser. How can I get errordetails which writing in middleware in side of Controller? I need to get this infos in TypeScript.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the next line after the context.response?Is the control returned from here or is it going to the next middleware in the pipeline?

Comment: Actually there is no return statement this context.response is last line in middleware. And there is only one middleware.

Comment: I think this is an exception which you should handle globally like this https://chrissainty.com/global-error-handling-aspnet-core-mvc/

Comment: What do you mean that you want to get the error message in typescript?Did you use typescript in asp.net core web api?Where did you want to show the message?